# linear search through uint64[] with SSE

Tags: c++, c, search, sse, linear-search

i'm trying to implement a linear search through an array of uint64 using SSE
instructions. I got things working for uint16 and uint32, but i get compiler
errors for the uint64 code (linux, gcc - see specs at the end).

I'm trying to compare 2x2 64bit numbers and then somehow translate the result
in an index for my array. This works well with uint32 (credits go to
http://schani.wordpress.com/2010/04/30/linear-vs-binary-search/):

```
#include <xmmintrin.h>
#include <smmintrin.h>

typedef ham_u64_t vec2uint64 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
typedef ham_u32_t vec4uint32 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
typedef float     vec4float  __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
typedef ham_u16_t vec8uint16 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
typedef ham_u8_t  vec16uint8 __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

// ...

vec4uint32 v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 0]);
vec4uint32 v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 4]);
vec4uint32 v3 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 8]);
vec4uint32 v4 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 12]);

vec4uint32 cmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v1);
vec4uint32 cmp1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v2);
vec4uint32 cmp2 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v3);
vec4uint32 cmp3 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v4);

vec8uint16 pack01 = __builtin_ia32_packssdw128(cmp0, cmp1);
vec8uint16 pack23 = __builtin_ia32_packssdw128(cmp2, cmp3);
vec16uint8 pack0123 = __builtin_ia32_packsswb128(pack01, pack23);

int res = __builtin_ia32_pmovmskb128(pack0123);
if (res > 0) {
  int czt = __builtin_ctz(~res + 1);
  return (start + i + czt);
}
```

Here's what i came up with so far for uint64. The comparison works, i just
don't know what to do with the results, and the __builtin_ia32_packssdw() call
does not compile:

```
vec2uint64 v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 0]);
vec2uint64 v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 2]);

vec2uint64 cmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v1);
vec2uint64 cmp1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v2);

vec4uint32 pack01 = __builtin_ia32_packssdw(cmp0, cmp1); // error
vec4uint32 pack23 = _mm_set1_epi32(0);
vec16uint8 pack0123 = __builtin_ia32_packsswb128(pack01, pack23);

int res = __builtin_ia32_pmovmskb128(pack0123);
if (res > 0) {
  int czt = __builtin_ctz(~res + 1);
  return (start + i + czt);
}
```

The error says:

```
error: cannot convert 'vec1uint64 {aka __vector(2) long unsigned int}'
to '__vector(2) int' for argument '1' to '__vector(4) short int
__builtin_ia32_packssdw(__vector(2) int, __vector(2) int)'
```

(The typedefs for vec2uint64 are at the top, in the code for uint32.)

My environment:

```
Linux ws4484 3.5.0-48-generic #72~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Tue Mar 11 20:09:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc version 4.6.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5)
```

My question is not just how i can fix the compiler error, but if somebody has a better idea to get the array index with the match, maybe without the whole
packing thing?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using low level intrinsics such as `__builtin_ia32_packssdw` instead of the more usual `_mm_packs_epi32` ? It makes dealing with the vector types a lot more messy.

Comment: No specific reason; i didn't know about _mm_packs_epi32. Thanks for your comment, i'll replace it.

Comment: If you use the normal high level intrinsics throughout then you can just use `__m128i` for all your vector variables and not worry about mixing different types for 32 bit and 64 bit operations, which as you have seen, can get ugly.

Comment: I followed your suggestion. Thanks for your help and your comments!

Comment: Are you writing in C, or in C++?

Comment: C++, but plain C is also fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest NOT using the built in intrinsics and implicit vectors.  This only makes sense if you don't use the non GCC intrinsics (e.g. _mm_cmpeq_epi32) and only want to stick to GCC.  You can do what you want like this

```
__m128i key2 = _mm_set1_epi64x(key);
__m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 0]);
__m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 2]);

__m128i cmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v1);
__m128i cmp1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v2);

__m128i low2  = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp0,0xD8);  
__m128i high2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp1,0xD8);      
__m128i pack = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(low2,high2);

__m128i pack01 = _mm_packs_epi32(pack, _mm_setzero_si128());
__m128i pack0123 = _mm_packs_epi16(pack01, _mm_setzero_si128());

int res =  _mm_movemask_epi8(pack0123);
```

You can probably find a more efficient version that avoids the packing but then you would have to use a different function than `__builtin_ctz`.

For 32-bit ints I suggest

```
__m128i key4 = _mm_set1_epi32(key);
__m128i v1 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 0]);
__m128i v2 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 4]);
__m128i v3 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 8]);
__m128i v4 = _mm_loadu_si128((const __m128i *)&data[start + i + 12]);

__m128i cmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v1);
__m128i cmp1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v2);
__m128i cmp2 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v3);
__m128i cmp3 = _mm_cmpeq_epi32(key4, v4);

__m128i pack01 = _mm_packs_epi32(cmp0, cmp1);
__m128i pack23 = _mm_packs_epi32(cmp2, cmp3);
__m128i pack0123 = _mm_packs_epi16(pack01, pack23);

int res = _mm_movemask_epi8(pack0123);
```

Comment: That works perfectly. Also thanks for the 32bit suggestions - I already replaced the intrinsics based on the suggestion of @Paul R.

Comment: I guess the GCC built in intrinsics have other advantages.  E.g. _mm_cmpeq_epi64 requires SSE4.1  for SSE2 it's complicated and the GCC intrinsics would take care of this for you.

Comment: For large arrays, you can make the inner loop faster if you just OR your cmp results together to see if there was any match.  Then outside the loop, sort out where the match was with shuffle/pack.  (This is like what [glibc's memchr](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S.html) does, but even more of a win because all that shuffling is expensive.)  Also, `_mm_packs_epi32` with zeros seems like a huge waste; just use `_mm_movemask_ps` to get the high bits of each dword element if you want a small bitmask.

Answer (score 3):

This is a complete solution for searching 64 bit values for a match.  In this case, the value (namehash) is a struct member.  This routine compares 8 64 bit values on each iteration and provides the matching struct index.

```
//ptr is a struct array
__m128i key2 = _mm_set1_epi64x(k); //k is the 64 bit search key
for(;;)
   {
   if(!ptr[i].namehash)return NULL;
   __m128i v1 = _mm_set_epi64x (ptr[i+1].namehash,ptr[i].namehash);
   __m128i v2 = _mm_set_epi64x (ptr[i+3].namehash,ptr[i+2].namehash);
   __m128i v3 = _mm_set_epi64x (ptr[i+5].namehash,ptr[i+4].namehash);
   __m128i v4 = _mm_set_epi64x (ptr[i+7].namehash,ptr[i+6].namehash);

   __m128i cmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v1);
   __m128i cmp1 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v2);
   __m128i cmp2 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v3);
   __m128i cmp3 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v4);

   __m128i L0  = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp0,0xD8);
   __m128i H1 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp1,0xD8);
   __m128i L2  = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp2,0xD8);
   __m128i H3 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp3,0xD8);

   __m128i pack0 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(L0,H1);
   __m128i pack1 = _mm_unpacklo_epi64(L2,H3);

   __m128i pack01 = _mm_packs_epi32(pack0,pack1);
   __m128i pack0123 = _mm_packs_epi16(pack01, _mm_setzero_si128());

   res =  _mm_movemask_epi8(pack0123);
   if(res > 0)break;
   i+=8;
   }

int index = i + __builtin_ctz(res);  //The struct table index to the matching struct.
```

IMPORTANT: The struct array length needs to be a multiple of 8, with at least 1 NULL trailing member

Alternatively, if only 2 64 bit comparisons are wanted per iteration, the above can be greatly simplified to:

```
for(;;)
   {
   if(!ptr[i].namehash)return NULL;
   __m128i v1 = _mm_set_epi64x (ptr[i+1].namehash,ptr[i].namehash);
   __m128i cmp0 = _mm_cmpeq_epi64(key2, v1);
   res =  _mm_movemask_epi8(cmp0);
   if(res > 0)break;
   i+=2;
   }
int ctz = __builtin_ctz(res);
int index = i + (ctz>>5);  //The struct table index to the matching struct.
```

Comment: For large arrays, you can make the inner loop faster if you just OR your cmp results together to see if there was any match.  Then outside the loop, sort out where the match was with shuffle/pack.  (This is like what [glibc's memchr](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/sysdeps/x86_64/memchr.S.html) does, but even more of a win because all that shuffling is expensive.)

Comment: Also, the last step of packing with zeros could be done by using `(__builtin_ctz(res)>>1)` instead, *outside* the loop if you don't want to optimize the loop to 4x pcmp + 3x por + pmovmskb

Answer (score 1):

I can't find any instructions to convert 64-bit integer to a 32-bit integer, which is what you need to then use packssdw, etc. It gets quite long and messy, but should work:

So, I think the solution is to use a bitmask (bits 0, 1, 2, 3:

These go before the loop:

```
vec2uint64 mask0 = { 2, 1 };
vec2uint64 mask1 = { 8, 4 };
vec2uint64 zero  = { 0, 0 };
```

Inside loop:

```
vec2uint64 res0 = _mm_and_si128(cmp0, mask0);
vec2uint64 res1 = _mm_and_si128(cmp1, mask1);

vec2uint64 res2 = _mm_or_si128(res0, res1);
```

Then we need to shuffle the high part to the low part of a new variable:

```
vec2uint64 hi0 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(res0, zero);
vec2uint64 hi1 = _mm_unpackhi_epi64(res1, zero);

vec2uint64 hi2 = _mm_or_si128(hi0, hi1);
vec2uint64 res3 = _mm_or_si128(res2, hi2);
```

Now the low 64 bits [well, the low 4 bits, the rest are zero] of res is a bitmask of which one of the values that matches.

```
int res = _mm_cvtsi128_si32(res3);
```

(Now you can count trailing zeros like before).

Comment: Packing four 64-bit values from two SSE register into four 32-bit values in one SSE register can be done with three intrinsics: `__m128i low2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp0,0xD8); __m128i high2 = _mm_shuffle_epi32(cmp1,0xD8); _mm_unpacklo_epi64(low2,high2)`.

Comment: I tried this function and it did not give consistent results for all my tests. It did find results, but the number of trailing zeroes was no longer correct. Nevertheless thanks for your answer, i appreciate it.